# issue with scheduling a powershell script in task scheduler windows 2008 server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to run a powershell script on the task scheduler but am unable to understand the suitable logging command for my script. I want to get this to run on the schedule.

The script would delete the files and folders older than x days and would create an output log.

```
function Out-Log {
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$message,
    [switch]$Error
    )
    $logPath = $env:TEMP + "\Filedeletion.log"
    $message | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append
    }
trap 
{
    "error:" | Out-Log 
    $_.exception.message | Out-Log
    break
}
$Error.Clear()
try 
{
    "Starting" | Out-Log
    $DateToDelete = 1
    $dateLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DateToDelete)
    $StartFolder = "c:\TEST1"
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Path $StartFolder | 
        foreach { 
            $currentItemIsFolder = $_.PsIsContainer;
            $curentItemIsOld = $_.LastWriteTime -lt $dateLimit
            if ($curentItemIsOld -and (-not $currentItemIsFolder))
            {
                "Removing '$($_.fullname)'." | Out-Log

                 Remove-Item -Path ($_.fullname) -Force -WhatIf

            }
        }

}
finally 
{
    if ($Error)
    {
        "`$error stack:" | Out-Log
          $error | foreach {$_.exception.ToString() |  Out-Log}
    }
    "Stopping" | Out-Log
}
```

I was trying to use

`Powershell -file "c:\Powershell\Filedeletion_logs_test.ps1"`

via batch to run the powershell.

I've tried to check the commands in Powershell/? but did not find any suitable logging command working for my script.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Normally, I'd just use start-transcript and use the -Verbose switch on the Remove-Item commands.

Comment: I wanted to schedule this in powershell command mode -verbose and I guess -verbose is unsupported logging command.

Comment: Try using start-transcript, and setting $VerbosePreference in your script to 'Continue'

Comment: Hi, I haven't used these transcripts till now in powershell so I am unaware of its positions in my current script. Is there any other alternative or can you share me some help to include them in my script.

Comment: I don't understand the problem... Is it that your logs don't work?

Comment: The only problem is that the script is not running in windows task scheduler. It runs manually and gives me logs and everything.

Comment: What is the execution policy of the user account under which the scheduled job runs? And the `%PATH%`? If you execute `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -file "c:\Powershell\Filedeletion_logs_test.ps1" -executionpolicy remotesigned` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a separate batch file that runs the powershell in the task schedule. All you need is this nice tutorial. It is detailed step by step, but is very easy to setup.
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do the same thing with SCHTASKS?

http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

You should be able to pipe a list of servers through a TYPE command and add the tasks to the server set.

For example:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntadmincommands.php

```
FOR /F %%A IN (servers.txt) DO (
SCHTASKS /CREATE /S %%A /U "system" /P "" /TN "Powershell Task" /TR "Powershell -file \"c:\my folder\script.ps1\"" 
)
```